# How can I %include C++ headers in SWIG when they contain namespaces?

Tags: c++, swig

I have a SWIG file that includes a C++ header.

Swig file:

```
%module my_module

%{
#include "my_c_file.h"
%}

%include "my_c_file.h"
```

C++ header:

```
namespace my_namespace {
  void Foo();
}
```

The generated _wrap.cc file does not compile and contains odd c++ like:

```
namespace arg1 ;
namespace *argp1 ;

argp1 = (namespace *)jarg1;
```

I suspect I'm missing some Swig command line option to get it to handle C++ namespaces correctly. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are not telling swig that the source files are C++ files. Using `swig -python -c++` has been working for us for a long time.

Change your command line appropriately and things should work.